# Merging table cells in rows with the same name into one cell or rowspan in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have data in one table that contains several rows of data for the same time. I would like to create a table where all the data for the same time is displayed on the same row and also date is displayed on the same row

My data is currently like this

Table Field like

```
date              time          product name       action

2015-08-20      8:00 AM         product one
2015-08-20      8:00 AM         product two
2015-08-20      8:00 AM         product three
2015-08-20      2:00 PM         product four
2015-08-20      2:00 PM         product five
2015-08-20      2:00 PM         product three
```

This is how I would like the data to be:

```
date              time          product name         action

                                product one
2015-08-20      8:00 AM         product two              print
                                product three

                                product four
2015-08-20      2:00 PM         product five             print
                                product three
```

Please somebody help me to find the answer

```
    $output = "";
        $getart2 = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM csv WHERE `date` = CURDATE() ");
        $result_array = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getart2)) {
             $result_array[] = $row;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already? please show what you have tried and where you have specific problems.

Comment: Sometimes i would really like to understand why some people consider questions like this wone worth upvoting. As it stands, it should be closed, or at least downvoted, for not showing any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution of many by grouping the data with array-keys:

```
$data = array(
    array('date' => '2015-08-20', 'time' => '8:00 AM', 'product_name' => 'product one'),
    array('date' => '2015-08-20', 'time' => '8:00 AM', 'product_name' => 'product two'),
    array('date' => '2015-08-20', 'time' => '8:00 AM', 'product_name' => 'product three'),
    array('date' => '2015-08-20', 'time' => '2:00 AM', 'product_name' => 'product four'),
    array('date' => '2015-08-20', 'time' => '2:00 AM', 'product_name' => 'product five'),
    array('date' => '2015-08-20', 'time' => '2:00 AM', 'product_name' => 'product six')
);
$data2 = array();
foreach($data as $value) {
    $key = $value['date'].$value['time'];
    if(!isset($data2[$key])) {
        $data2[$key] = array('date' => $value['date'], 'time' => $value['time'], 'product_name' => array());
    }
    $data2[$key]['product_name'][] = $value['product_name'];
}

$output = '<table>';
$output .= '<tr><th>date</th><th>time</th><th>product name</th></tr>';
foreach($data2 as $row) {
    $output .= '<tr>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$row['time'].'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.implode('<br />', $row['product_name']).'</td>';
    $output .= '</tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: how to fetch from database directly and my code is  $output = "";
 $getart2 = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM csv WHERE `d_date` = CURDATE() ");

Comment: how to get $data from database directly

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_query() anymore it's deprecated. http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php has some snippets for fetching data from MySQL.

Comment: My problem solved thanks i just forgot to add $output = '<table>';
$output .= '<tr><th>date</th><th>time</th><th>product name</th></tr>'; $output .= '</table>';so that i am not getting the right result.

Comment: After merging cells how to insert into that data into database